# What is the reaction that takes place in the cathode of a Mg-Fe electrochemical cell?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

> #### Setup
>
> A magnesium electrode dipped in a magnesium sulfate solution and an iron electrode dipped into iron (III) sulfate solution

Am I right in thinking that you need to first identify the redox reactions to determine to determine overall voltage of the cell at standard conditions?

I have identified $\ce{Mg}$ to be oxidized to $\ce{Mg^2+}$ at the anode, but I am not sure which is reduced at the cathode. Would it be the sulfate ions?

Comment: @Mithoron Oxidize to sulfurous acid?

Comment: Sulfate can indeed be reduced by magnesium as magnesium is very strongly reducing, and you would get $E^\circ = +2.54\mathrm{~V}$ as you said, but there's probably a stronger oxidising agent than sulfate in that $\ce{Fe2(SO4)3}$ solution.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] I am not sure which is reduced at the cathode. Would it be the sulfate ions?

*orthocresol* has already pointed out in his comment that there's more in $\ce{Fe2(SO4)3}$ than just the sulfate.

Take a look at the cation:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{Fe^3+& + e- &<=>&Fe^2+\quad &+0.77V} \\
\ce{Fe^3+& + 3e- &<=>&Fe(s)\quad &-0.04V}
\end{align}$$

(Standard electrode potentials are cited from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)).)